# Extension function of String class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I want to create an extension function of `String` which takes a `String` and returns a new `String` with the characters as the first, but sorted in ascending order. How can I do this? I am new to Kotlin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fun String.ascending() = String(toCharArray().sortedArray())
```

Then:

```
println("14q36w25e".ascending())  // output "123456eqw"
```

Answer (score 4):

Extension function for printing characters of a string in ascending order

**Way 1:**

```
fun String.sortStringAlphabetically() = toCharArray().sortedArray())
```

**Way 2:**

```
fun String.sortStringAlphabetically() = toCharArray().sortedArrayDescending().reversedArray()
```

**Way 3:**

```
fun String.sortStringAlphabetically() = toCharArray().sorted().joinToString(""))
```

**Way 4:**

```
fun String.sortStringAlphabetically() = toCharArray().sortedBy{ it }.joinToString(""))
```

Then you can use this extension function by the below code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("41hjhfaf".sortStringAlphabetically())
}
```

Output: `14affhhj`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine built in extensions to do it quickly:

```
fun String.sortedAlphabetically() = toCharArray().apply { sort() }
```

First you get array of underlying characters, then you apply sort to that array and return it. You are free to cast result `.toString()` if You need.

Comment: why do you use the apply ? why not `toCharArray().sort()` directly ?

Comment: `sort()` returns `Unit`, `apply` returns receiver object (`CharArray`).

Answer (score 2):

I have one more:

```
fun String.inAscending(): String = toMutableList().sortedBy { it }.joinToString("")
```

And better:

```
fun String.ascending(): String = toMutableList().sorted().joinToString("")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, do it in **kotlin** way i.e

```
fun String.sortAscending() = toCharArray().sortedBy{ it }.joinToString("")
```